# CRC Calculations in C - Adding single bit function to Ross Williams Library

Tags: c, arm, crc

Good morning !

For a wireless application i need to implement various CRC-Caluclations. According to the Specification, the CRC-Calculation should be implemented as a Shift Register. [See EPC Spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0FFk.png)

There is a excellent guide called "A PAINLESS GUIDE TO CRC ERROR DETECTION ALGORITHMS" by Ross N. Williams, which includes a universal C implementation i would like to use. [(Link including the SourceCode)](https://web.archive.org/web/20161126040242/http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt)

The problem is that the included function only takes complete bytes as input.
My messages can have various lengths.

Here is the code for adding a byte:

```
void cm_nxt(p_cm,ch)
    p_cm_t p_cm;
    int    ch;
{
    int   i;
    ulong uch  = (ulong)ch;
    ulong topbit = BITMASK(p_cm->cm_width - 1);

    if (p_cm->cm_refin) uch = reflect(uch, 8);
    p_cm->cm_reg ^= (uch << (p_cm->cm_width - 8));
    for (i = 0;  i <8; i++) {
        if (p_cm->cm_reg & topbit)
            p_cm->cm_reg = (p_cm->cm_reg << 1) ^ p_cm->cm_poly;
        else
            p_cm->cm_reg <<= 1;
        p_cm->cm_reg &= widmask(p_cm);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to implement a function just to add one Bit to the calculation. 
I tried the following code:

```
void cm_nxt_bit(p_cm, ch)
    p_cm_t p_cm;
    int    ch;
{
    ulong uch  = (ulong)ch;
    ulong topbit = BITMASK(p_cm->cm_width - 1);

    if (p_cm->cm_refin) uch = reflect(uch, 8);
    p_cm->cm_reg ^= (uch << (p_cm->cm_width - 8));

    if (p_cm->cm_reg & topbit)
        p_cm->cm_reg = (p_cm->cm_reg << 1) ^ p_cm->cm_poly;
    else
        p_cm->cm_reg <<= 1;
    p_cm->cm_reg &= widmask(p_cm);
}
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work as intended.
Can you help me to implement such a function ?

Comment: **One** problem is there are different ways to add dangling bits. Problem is, most implementations do not accept them, resp. pad them to the next byte in a specific way. As we are no clairvoyants, I'm afraid we cannot know what you intend. As a sidenote: don't use signed integers when shifting and for CRC algorithms. And use fixed-width types, not the standard integer types.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the one bit at the *top* of the register, just like the other code put the one byte at the top of the register. Assuming that `ch` must be either `0` or `1`, so that the bit you are adding is the bottom bit of `ch`, you then need to shift `uch` up by `cm_width-1`, not `cm_width-8` before exclusive-oring into the register.

Also get rid of the use of `reflect`. The reflection of one bit is that same one bit.

Also you can look my [crcany code](https://github.com/madler/crcany), which generates CRC code in C for any CRC definition, including a routine that will compute the CRC of the last 1 to 7 bits of a stream if it is not a multiple of eight bits in length.

Comment: @easter91: count your blessings! Your CRC question was answered by **the** Mark Adler, inventor of the famous adler32 checksum function used in the zlib compression library.

Comment: talking about CRCs and error correction, were you involved in the most admirable application of these techniques: the remote update of the Voyager firmware, many years after launch, to take advantage of these techniques and extend the mission by an amazing two decades? Any programmer interested in science should visit JPL when passing through LA.

Comment: No, I never worked on Voyager. Those updates were before my time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to generate C files using yout crcgen tool form crcany.

Comment: Unfortunately i do not get the right results... CRC16/GENIBUS of 110000010000000011110000 (0xC100F0) should be 1100110110111011. So i do the following :uint16_t crc=0;
 Bool bit;


 bit=1;
 crc = crc16genibus_bit(crc,&bit,1);
 bit=1;
 crc = crc16genibus_bit(crc,&bit,1);

Comment: The `_bit` function processes a _byte_ a bit at a time. The correct usage would be `crc16genibus_bit(crc16genibus_bit(0, NULL, 0), "\xc1\x00\xf0", 3)`. Using the corresponding `_byte` or `_word` function will give you exactly the same result. If you want to process a number of bits that is not a multiple of 8, then use one of the functions above, followed by the `_rem` function for the remaining 1 to 7 bits.